# 1996 Corolla won't start in the cold (starts/runs great above 40F)

Tags: toyota, corolla

My 1996 corolla cranks, but will not start unless it is above freezing. However, above 40F it starts and runs great, no issues at all.

Already I have replaced the spark plugs, wires, checked the distributor cap. Also put in a new air filter for what it is worth. I pulled the valve cover, the timing belt looks great. Drove it 300 miles yesterday (nice 60F degree day) not a single issue.

Edit: I also replaced the fuel pump.

Edit 2: I also replaced the engine coolant temperature sensor (suggested elsewhere). No effect. As soon as the outside temperature is in the 30's cannot get it started. Above 40F it starts on the first turn. PLEASE help

Comment: When it cranks, does it sound normal? How old is your battery?

Comment: Thanks for the question. The battery is just over 3 years old. Holds a charge great. I can crank for a good long while on cold days  I have even supplemented it with a boost pack to rule out low battery juice as an option. When cranking starter sounds normal. It is almost as if it just cannot make combustion happen. I failed to mention earlier that I also replaced the fuel pump to rule that out as well.

Comment: Does the car have an ODB connector? If so, what fault codes are stored?

Comment: @david yes it does. No fault codes.

Comment: Is your climate at all damp? On a below 40F night, open the hood and have a friend crank the starter. Can you see sparkles on the distributor cap? If so, I'd suspect that very small (read: invisible in daylight) cracks in the cap are shorting the HT to ground.

Comment: Thanks @david for the continued input. No dampness lately. Distributor cap looks OK. Didn't start the other day on a sub-freezing day. Today, low 50's (love Spring time), and she fired right up! But I was overjoyed to finally get a check engine light. OBO II code is P0120 (Throttle Pedal Position sensor/switch a circuit malfunction).

Comment: Already so.e googling around has caused me to suspect the cold start injector, but hadn't had time yet to pull it, clean, and retry (and a new one is a bit costly).

Comment: That sounds promising. And...I'm out of ideas. Good luck with it, report back so we know what you discover.

Comment: @David my apologies. I did not update this thread. Turns out there is not a cold start injector on the 1996 Corolla. Others report this function is controlled by the PCM. Replacing the  computer is a bit expensive for me now. The weather is changing and only 1 or 2 days a week is it under 40F. I might wait until Fall when the cold weather is here to stay again to replace the PCM. (Unless anyone is able to offer an alternative option to try. My local mechanic seems stumped too.)